# How to determine Arc's Orientation in Java

Tags: java, orientation, automatic-ref-counting, counterclockwise

I am generating 2D arcs using the following code.

```
final Arc2D.Double arcPath = new Arc2D.Double();
arcPath.setArcByCenter(centerPoint.getX(), centerPoint.getY(), radius, fDXFArc.getStartAngle(), fDXFArc.getTotalAngle(), Arc2D.OPEN);
```

The arcs are perfectly rendered on my Canvas but I do not know if they are Clockwise or Counter Clockwise. Can someone share the algorithm to detect the arc's orientation ?

Comment: Nice riddle :-)

Comment: @user16320675 To better understand my problem use an arc starting at 0 degrees and ending at 180degrees. Is it CW or CCW ?

Comment: there are two possible arcs starting at 0° and ending at 180° (or almost any other angles,) it is your choice - I gave the answer for posted code : if `getTotalAngle()` returns a negative value, the arc is CW; if the value is positive, the arc is CCW - I cannot see what `getTotalAngle()` is actually calculating/returning.

Answer (score 0):

I see two hints for `always counterclockwise` (80% sure):

First `java.awt.geom.Arc2D` itself tells in it's class description:

```
* The angles are specified relative to the non-square
* framing rectangle such that 45 degrees always falls on the line from
* the center of the ellipse to the upper right corner of the framing
* rectangle.
```

This can only be true if `0 degrees` are at `12 pm` and degrees measured `clockwise` or `3 pm` and degrees measured `counterclockwise`.

Second `public void setAngles()` in the same package measure degrees `counterclockwise`:

```
* The arc will always be non-empty and extend counterclockwise
* from the first point around to the second point.
```

following that it would make sense to follow the same pattern in all functions of that class.

If you need to be sure: Ask the author of that class:

```
 * @author      Jim Graham
```

Comment: To better understand my problem use an arc starting at 0 degrees and ending at 180degrees. Is it CW or CCW ?

Comment: @Nikos this would be CCW

Answer (score -1):

I actually manage to determine my Arcs direction. I just **splitted every arc that is larger than 180degrees to 2 smaller arcs** and I use the following code

```
Point startPoint = arc.getBorderPoint(EBorderPoint.StartPoint);
Point endPoint = arc.getBorderPoint(EBorderPoint.EndPoint);
Point centerPoint = arc.getBorderPoint(EBorderPoint.CenterPoint);

final double result = (endPoint.getX() - startPoint.getX()) * (centerPoint.getY() - startPoint.getY()) - (endPoint.getY() - startPoint.getY()) * (centerPoint.getX() - startPoint.getX());
boolean isClockWise = result > 0 ? false : true;

if (result == 0)
{
    // Since I splitted the large arcs to 2 smaller arcs 
    // the code will never go to this if statement      
}
```